# Angular js redirect URL on same page?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am building an node js app within which I have one page on angular js. On one of the pages, all the users are listed down(as hyperlinks) and I click on one of them to access the information about that user.

So, if the first page's URL(i.e. all the users) is /users, I want the second URL to look like /users/:id. So, in a way I want to mimic the REST API format.

The user's info has been found and once the user-id has been found, I m trying to use $location.path(index).

Initially I thought using something like ng-if would help me in rendering using the same page. So, on my .jade file, I have added this condition:

```
div(ng-show='loadAllUsers()')

$scope.loadAllUsers = function(){
            console.log($scope.index == -1)
            return $scope.index == -1;
        };
```

$scope.index has been initialized to -1. So, I thought something like this would work when a new id value has been generated. But, the problem is it doesn't seem to reload the whole page or div.. I tried using window.location.href as well. That, even though updated the URL but even that breaks...

So, is there a way on doing this on the same jade file by any chance? If not , then how exactly should I go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {
  
  $scope.userDetails={};
   //get the list of users from data base. here i am taking some dummy values.
    $scope.users=[{
      id:1,
      name:"Rahul"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"Ajay"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:"Mohit"
    }];  
  
  // get user details
  $scope.getUserDetails=function(userId){
      UserService.get({id:userId},function(userDetails){
        $scope.userDetails=userDetails;
      });
    };
    
});
  
   // No need to change the page URL. Above function will 
   // call 'UserService' factory. UserService will communicate 
   // with REST API with URL pattern 'app/rest/users/:id'.  
   // ':id' will be replaced by the id passed by above function. 
   // like 'app/rest/users/2'
    
angular.module('myApp').factory('UserService',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('app/rest/users/:id', {}, {
          get':{method:'GET', isArray: false}
    });
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td ng-click="getUserDetails(user.id)">{{user.name}}</td>
      <tr>
    </table> 
 </div>
 <div>
   <h3>User Details</h3>
      id : userDetails.id <br/>
      name : userDetails.name <br/>
    // other details
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well this almost works.. One thing that I forgot to mention is that I also have a search button at the top. So, I can search users using their names as well. And once I do that, I need to replace the content of the page with the user details.. I guess, in your case, the userDEtails are also shown as well as all the users.. To mimic this, I added an if statement in my jade file... if userDetails  <userdetails code> else <all users> This doesn;t seem to work though.. Also, clicking the button doesn't lead anywhere....